# Convert ListView to ListView.builider

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering how can convert it to ListView.builider if any one got any idea

................................................................................................................

```
ListView(
                        children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                          String ct = document['category'];
                          Timestamp ca = document['createdAt'];
                          String des = document['description'];
                          String id = document['id'];
                          String image = document['image'];
                          String image2 = document['image2'];
                          String image3 = document['image3'];
                          String title = document['title'];
                          String owner = document['Owner'];
                          Offer offer = new Offer(
                            id: id,
                            title: title,
                            category: ct,
                            image: image,
                            image2: image2,
                            image3: image3,
                            description: des,
                            createdAt: ca,
                            owner: owner,
                          );

                          return ProductCard(offer);
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs == null ? 0 : snapshot.data.docs.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final document = snapshot.data.docs[index];
    String ct = document['category'];
    Timestamp ca = document['createdAt'];
    String des = document['description'];
    String id = document['id'];
    String image = document['image'];
    String image2 = document['image2'];
    String image3 = document['image3'];
    String title = document['title'];
    String owner = document['Owner'];
    Offer offer = Offer(
      id: id,
      title: title,
      category: ct,
      image: image,
      image2: image2,
      image3: image3,
      description: des,
      createdAt: ca,
      owner: owner,
    );
    return ProductCard(offer);
  },
),
```